# XCode 4.4 remote Image in a Custom Cell Table View

Tags: uitableview, storyboard, xcode4.4, custom-cell

I'm new in Xcode Programming and I'm developing a small application but I have a problem.

I have a Table View with a Custom Cell, taking externally the data to populate the view (by JSon). I have a big slow navigation in list because in the method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. I get an external image and this makes it all slow because it runs every time a cell displayed.

How can I populate the entire list without using this method? Or is there an alternative to make it understand that the image exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few methods Apple suggests when customizing your UITableViewCell. You probably is trying to add subviews to the contentView of the cell. A better approach is described here [Subclassing UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW12). Well, I suggest you read the [TableView Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1).

Comment: I understood thats what you are trying. It reuses the image. Instead of adding subviews to the contentView you can try the third method apple suggests. Make a custom view and lay out your UI Elements as subviews to the custom view. The custom view will go in as a subview for your cell's content view. You have better control for encapsulation by adopting this style

Comment: my problem probably derive from this string "[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];"...Apple suggests to reuse a cell and in this case when i load a remote image for a single cell, it load the same image for other "reuse" cell and this make my list slowly...this is my code
<code>
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [cell.img setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]];return cell;
}
</code>

Comment: do you have an example?refering to apple guide, you mean "Customizing Cells" block?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318

Comment: those example are not update to storyboard, i don't want to change everything without storyboard :( however i don't have a subclass..i make a custom cell, put in an UIImageView e some UILbale, create a UITableViewCell for this item and set the cell item from code write before..some idea?